# Cannot import library on Haxe & FlashDevelop

Tags: import, haxe, flashdevelop, haxeflixel, haxelib

I added some classes through http://lib.haxe.org/ and git with the correct command (haxelib install x) and, while the classes are in the haxe/lib folder, I can't access most of them. Sometimes I'm able to import a library(I get the autocomplete and everything), but when I try to compile it gives me the error `Class not found`.

I searched everywhere and I still don't know how to fix this. I tried to add through Project>Properties>Classpath and I'd even edited the global Classpath but it still won't work. Right now my problem is with the library linden-google-play but I tried with another libraries and it didn't work either.

AdMob and Firetongue libraries work perfectly, and I can't understand why. Does anyone knows a way to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out how to do it. You have to go to `Project.xml` and add the library name manually.

```
<haxelib name="openfl" />
<haxelib name="task" />
```

Comment: That is what changing the "project properties" do :) ... you should not need to change the project file by hand.

Comment: Actually, changing the project properties doesn't do anything for OpenFL projects (which is why they [should be read-only](https://github.com/fdorg/flashdevelop/pull/547)), since it's all determined by the OpenFL project file.

Comment: In the original question there was no mention of openfl so I assumed it was a "normal" haxe project.

Comment: No, don't be sorry. Great question and great answer. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the class path configuration that is reserved for your local projects/libraries. Go to Project Properties>Compiler Options>Libraries and add one library per line (the lib name must match what you used in `haxelib install ...`).