# HaxeFlixel... type not found : flixel.FlxGame

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

```
package;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.Lib;
import flixel.FlxGame;
import flixel.FlxState;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Jacob
 */ 
class Main extends Sprite 
{
    var gameWidth:Int = 800;
    var gameHeight:Int = 480;
    var initialState:Class<FlxState> = PlayState;
    var zoom:Float = -1;
    var Framerate:Int = 60;
    var skipSplash:Bool = false;
    var startFullscreen:Bool = false;

    public function new() 
    {
        super();        
    }
}
```

Some preliminary stuff, just in case...

Windows 10
I have all of the dependencies and haxeflixel installed with haxelib
I'm using the latest version of Haxe, downloaded and installed yesterday.
I'm programming in FlashDevelop.

```
import flixel.FlxGame
```

...gets underlined in red, and I get the error

```
type not found : flixel.FlxGame
```

...at compile, I've had a single case where simply retyping that (without any kind of change in what was typed, no typos corrected) fixed the problem, but I have not been able to replicate. I have this project compiled, just not the latest one, this error cropped up out of nowhere and has prevented me from getting any farther.

I've had the same problem in my PlayState with import flixel.FlxObject as well.

What is going on here? I have compiled the FlxSnake example among other things, so I don't believe that it's an issue with my installation, but I can't imagine what could be wrong with an *import*.

Edit: I didn't follow the standard architecture for a flixel project, intending to try for a minimalist, single file practice project initially.

Comment: Have you added the dependency to flixel to your project settings or hxml file?

Comment: @jonasmalacofilho No, I haven't, I didn't realize it was necessary. Now I've tried editing the hxproj file and adding the library, but every time I load it in FlashDevelop it is reset to the way it was before, sans library. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know, I'm sorry. I haven't used FlashDevelop in quite some time.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt anyway!

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27789617/2801377) answer?

Comment: Those options are all greyed out for me when I try to change them, they don't do anything. 

I'm working through a template made from the command line to move my code over (brand new to Haxe, Haxeflixel and pretty new to architecture in general, so I'll be at it a while), so far so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you create the project? `Project -> New Project` in FlashDevelop? Provided you chose the correct project type ("OpenFL"), there should be a `project.xml` configuration file which is used for compilation (some docs on the format can be found [here](http://www.openfl.org/documentation/projects/project-files/xml-format/)). That file has to include the flixel library via `<haxelib name="flixel" />`.

However, there's not really much of a reason to do all this manually. It's recommended to [use flixel-tools to create projects from an existing template](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/flixel-tools/). Alternatively, there's a FlashDevelop template available [here](http://haxeflixel.com/download/) ("FlashDevelop .fdz template").

You can pretty much ignore the `.hxproj` file, that's a FlashDevelop Haxe project file and not intended to be edited manually.

Comment: I imagine this worked, but now I'm getting other errors with my code that I need to figure out before I can be sure.

Comment: I made a new project from a template and it compiled without this error, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for people who had the same problem the only way to resolve it without starting from scratch is to add  " import flixel.FlxG;"